# Shell script self-incremental count as the array index

Tags: bash, shell

below is a simple shell script code iterating an income file and save the line into an array. But shouldn't the line#4 be like:
cusips[$i] rather than cusips[i]? or it doesn't matter? seems both worked.

Thanks,
john

```
 i=0  #line1
while read line # Read a line #line2
do #3
    cusips[i]=$line # Put it into the array #line4
    i=$(($i + 1)) #line5
done < $1 #line6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is in whether or not the value will be substituted *before* the evaluation of the arithmetic expression.

For example, these are all the same:

```
array=(1 1 2 3 5)
i=0
echo "${array[i]}"   # Look up the variable i
echo "${array[$i]}"  # Substitute the value of i: look up the value 0
echo "${array[0]}"   # Look up the value 0, just like above
```

However, it makes a difference when you start doing operations on variables rather than values:

```
echo "${array[i++]}"   # Increment variable i
echo "${array[$i++]}"  # 0++: syntax error: operand expected
echo "${array[0++]}"   # Makes no sense, just like above
```

Since you can increment a variable but not a number (`i++` works but `0++` doesn't), you can not substitute the variable for its contents before evaluating it with `$`.

The same is true for all other syntax that evaluates as arithmetic expressions, like `$((..))`. You can replace yours with `(( i++ ))` but not `(( $i++ ))`.

---

Note that if you use associative arrays, the index will be evaluated as a string and not an arithmetic expression, so `${array[i]}` would look up the letter `i` while `${array[$i]}` would look up the number `0`.

Comment: Could you clarify your final paragraph? Your 2 examples look identical to me - maybe I'm mis-reading something?

Comment: Oops, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

In a couple different places (for example, [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html#Shell-Arithmetic)) I saw this sentence:

> Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

Within the square brackets of an array, things are interpreted within the context of an arithmetic expression. According to the (somewhat terse) sentence above, you don't need the "parameter expansion syntax" in this context which I take to mean the $-sign preceding the variable name.

If you include the $-sign then normal parameter expansion makes it work; if you don't put it in then this rule related to an arithmetic expression makes it work. The end result is they both work and you can take your pick!